# wordpress: how to secure attachments from other users

Tags: wordpress

As a admin I created some posts with attachments and allowed permissions to particular users it works fine no other member or non-member can access those posts but what about the attachments everyone can access those attachments.

I read http://www.idowebdesign.ca/wordpress/password-protect-wordpress-attachments/ but I don't want to use `.htaccess`. Is there any good wp plugin which do this?

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing WP can do if we type a Jpeg URL in the browser. Also, you don't specify if you're talking about front or back end...

Comment: I am talking about back-end

Answer (score -1):

You can download the SEO by Yoast plugin.  In that there are settings to apply a no-index etc. to make the content un-discoverable by search and the sitemap.

You could also use membership plugins like imember360 (formerly infusionwp) or Premise (by coppyblogger people)

There are quite a few ways to secure attachments etc.

I guess my question would be can anyone see the page where the attachments are, or is it a page you give them a link to?

Thanks!